# Is the cartesian product of groups the product of a normal subgroup and its quotient group?

Tags: group-theory

I'm studying elementary group theory, and just seeing the ways in which groups break apart into simpler groups, specifically, a group can be broken up as the sort of product of any of its normal subgroups with the quotient group of that subgroup. So I wondered how you could do the inverse of that operation:

1. Given two groups $A$ and $B$, construct a group $G$ which admits a normal subgroup $H$ isomorphic to $A$, such that $G/H$ is isomorphic to $B$.

I think I have a proof that the cartesian product $A \times B$ (with the usual component-wise operation) verifies (1), but since I'm just starting out I'm not totally confident in my construction. Furthermore, if I'm right, is this the *only* group up to isomorphism satisfying (1)?

Edit: I just noticed [Proving the direct product D of two groups G & H has a normal subgroup N such that N isomorphic to G and D/N isomorphic to H](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220487/proving-the-direct-product-d-of-two-groups-g-h-has-a-normal-subgroup-n-such-th?rq=1), which seems to positively answer my question. In that case I'd like to draw attention to the follow up question above (uniqueness up to isomorphism).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the direct product $A \times B$ satisfies the property, as you've noticed. But it's not unique up to isomorphism. For example, the [dihedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group) $D_n$ has a normal subgroup $H \simeq \mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z$, with $G/H \simeq \mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z$, but $D_n$ is not isomorphic (for $n > 1$) to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.

More generally, you're asking whether, given an [exact sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence) of the form $1 \to N \to G \to H \to 1$, is $G$ isomorphic to $N \times H$? The answer is no, as I've shown. Many counterexamples are provided by [semidirect products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-direct_product) (something you'll learn soon enough if you're studying elementary group theory).

For abelian groups, the concept of [Ext functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor) allows one to classify all such extensions (given abelian groups $A,B$, "how many" groups $G$ are there with an exact sequence $0 \to B \to G \to A \to 0$ is given by $\mathrm{Ext}(A,B)$), but this is much more advanced.

Comment: If each of A,B,C is abelian and the sequence 0 -> A -> B -> C -> 0, what would be some restrictions on A, C that would ensure that B is isomorphic to A x C? What if A and C are cyclic?

Answer (score 4):

You're correct that $A\times B$ *satisfies* ([see here](http://www.jmilne.org/math/words.html)) the stated property, but in general it will not be the only such group.

The simplest example is with $A=B=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, in which case $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ also has the desired property.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea about the direct product working is true. The general idea you are looking for however is that of a [semidirect product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) which refutes your claim of uniqueness in the general setting.

It's interesting to ask *when* the direct product is the only possibility and that can actually be answered by finding the group $\text{Ext}(B,A)$. This is know as an [extension problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_problem#Extension_problem). We have that if $\text{Ext}(B,A)=1$ then $A\times B$ is the unique extension of $B$ by $A$.

I believe the converse is false however, but I can't think of an example at the moment. That is, there exist pairs $(B,A)$ such that $\text{Ext}(B,A)\neq 1$ but $B\times A$ is the unique (up to group isomorphism, not extension equivalence) extension of $B$ by $A$.